# Battery State in System differs largely from BIOS

Tags: 20.04, dell, laptop, battery

I'm running 20.04 on my Dell Precision 5530 laptop and the battery state as reported by the system tells me a quite low capacity of only 67%. The BIOS of the system reports that the battery capacity is still at 98%, which seems more reasonably to me.
Is there an option to re-calibrate the value Ubuntu show or tell it the right one? Guess the current state might actually influence the battery life of my system as it might not charge as it should. But I am not sure about that, since charging is usually controlled by the BIOS.